# Can window2000 install the .net3.5 sp1?

Tags: .net-3.5

if you know, please teach me how to install.
And i will try to install it in window2000 at the same time.
thx a lot.

Comment: This just sounds like a headache. Why not get new computers? I can't imagine trying to run ANYTHING developed with .NET 3.5 on a Windows 2000 machine. The thought of it makes me shudder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't officially support .Net 3.5 in win 2000, but you can take a look at how people tried that:

http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2008/03/12/microsoft-net-framework-35-in-windows-2000/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the system requirements - it clearly does not have Windows 2000 on the "Supported Operating Systems" list.